# Film that involves a young couple being lured or hypnotized by some foreign being

Tags: identify-this-movie

In the early 2000's when I was still a pretty young kid, I remember watching a movie with my parents one afternoon on TV. From what I remember, the quality of the actual film itself was pretty bad. I'm guessing the movie can't be more current than the late 70's maybe early 80's.

I don't remember much of the plot, except I know for sure that there was a young couple somehow stranded or lost in a foreign environment. They were both white maybe early twenties and I believe the girl was blonde. Almost everything I remember about the movie is not 100% definite. The one vivid part that stands out in my mind is a scene where the couple had been separated and the male ended up finding the female again. They talked for several minutes and he was urging her to leave the area. She was listening to some type of loud creepy/eerie siren or horn that sounded across the land. She was instantly hypnotized and put in a zombie like  trance. The male repeatedly tried to snap her out of it but no matter what he did he could not, so he ended up having to quietly follow her to where she was being led.

After several minutes of walking, she reached a large hole in the ground and that is where the sound was signaling her too. That is the only part of the plot I can chronologically describe. I'm almost positive the creatures behind the Hypnotic siren or horn were some type of strange short trolls or aliens and there several of them. I couldn't even tell you the genre of this film, but my best guess would be horror or sci-fi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The Time Machine"(1960)?
This definitely sounds like it, it has a blonde character played by Yvette Mimieux and a main character played by Rod Taylor. Here is the scene you are referring to from Youtube.

In this clip you can see Rod Taylor climbing into the 'hole in the ground', which is part of an old missile silo? You can also hear the siren and see that it puts the people of this future world into a trance.

Here is a still photo of the Morelocks, which I believe are the creatures you called 'short trolls', they are the ones who sound the siren to round up the people who live above ground. They herd them underground like cattle so they can eat them.

http://www.coolasscinema.com/2013/07/out-of-this-world-sci-fi-classics-time.html